# How to make Nautilus location bar editable?

Tags: nautilus

In Thunar I could easily switch between Vista-style graphical location bar and editable textual location bar (which doesn't look so eye-candy but is far more convenient for me). Can I configure this in Nautilus?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- If you want to enable location bar for current session then Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
  [image]
- To make it permanent you have to make changes in gconf-editor.Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type **gconf-editor**.
  [image]
- Navigate to apps **→** nautilus **→** preferences and put a check mark in "always_use_location_entry".
  [image]

Answer (score 3):

note for 11.10 >

"Note that as from Ubuntu 11.10 the setting is no longer in gconf but has moved to dconf. It is necessary to install dconf-tools then run dconf-editor and the setting will be found in org ➜ gnome ➜ nautilus ➜ preferences ➜ always-use-location-entry"

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreNautilusLocationBar