# How to navigate to a folder by pasting/typing it in file manager of ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, filemanager, navigation, copy-and-paste

In the file manager of ubuntu 18.04 (launched by clicking the second icon in the left taskbar), supposing I have copied a string of folder name, where can I paste (or type) the folder name, press return and the file manager will navigate to that folder, just as in Windows Explorer? Thanks.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to make Nautilus location bar editable?
Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21924/how-to-make-nautilus-location-bar-editable)

Comment: Thank you, steeldriver. Ctrl-L is the key.

Comment: Control + L works in some other programs too, like web browsers.